# Content is deleted But URL still crawled

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, seo, drupal-search

I have deleted some content from my website, but google search still shows me that content's url , after clicking on that url i get page not found error, please give me any link of drupal website to handle this situation.

Thanks & Regards,
Abbas Mulani

Comment: It will take a little time for Google to update its index, and you have nothing to very little to do about that.

Comment: Add those pages to noindex in robot.txt file in your Drupal root

Answer (score 1):

Create a Google Webmasters account and add your site. (all info on how to add available in Google webmasters itself).

Once you have done that you can submit list of URLs to Google to remove it from index, it might take a day or two. But this is the fastest way to get them removed.